# Error: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":".//*[@id='billing:firstname']"}

Tags: selenium

Somebody please help me. I am simply trying to enter the text into the text box, but facing same error from a long time.

I have a constructor class and main class:

> Unable to locate element:
>   {"method":"xpath","selector":".//*[@id='billing:firstname']"} Command
>   duration or timeout: 20.24 seconds

CODE:

```
@Test
public void FillFormPTC() throws InterruptedException {

    SecondCat home= new SecondCat(driver);

    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    // driver.switchTo().defaultContent();
    // WebElement input = (new WebDriverWait(driver, 25)).until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.xpath(".//*[@id='billing:firstname']")));
    home.TextFirstname("joe");    
}
```

Comment: WebDriver is unable to locate the element. Read about Xpath from w3c website and write a proper xpath. For quick solution try changing xpath to id like this... By.id("billing:firstname")

Comment: can you try the below xpath `By.xpath(".//*[contains(@id,'firstname')]"))`

Comment: Please add the relevant section of the HTML to your question.

Comment: I have already tried By.id, still not working.

Comment: please paste the 4-5 lines html of web element

Comment: Did you look for frame/iframe?? Make sure this element is not inside any frame/iframe??